# How can I prove the law of excluded third (p ∨ ¬p)) using Fitch?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, fitch

Good day.
I do not quite understand how I can get ~~p after the 11th line.

[image: partial proof of p or not p]

According to the proof of the law itself (and all reasonable logic) I should get it, and then simplify the expression - but I can not do it.

[image: The law of excluded third.]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need Double Negation. See the post [Proving 'Law of Excluded Middle' in Fitch system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054315/proving-law-of-excluded-middle-in-fitch-system).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks, I'll find my mistake.)

Answer (score 1):

> Good day. I do not quite understand how I can get ~~p after the 11th line.

Good day.  You do not necessarily require `~~p` to contradict `~p`, you simply need *some* contradiction to be derivable from assuming `~(p | ~p)`.  Well, `(p | ~p)` contradicts the assumption itself, so...

Don't reiterate on line 10.  The sub-proof is complete (for your purpose) at line 9.

```
 Line 1  |_ ~(p | ~p)               Assumption
      :  :                          : as you had.
 Line 9  |  (p | ~p)                Or Introduction  8
```

From here the next line is instead *conditional introduction*.

```
 Line 10 ~(p | ~p) => (p | ~p)      => Introduction  1-9
```

After this, if only you could *somehow* derive `~(p | ~p) => ~(p | ~p)` then you may apply the Stanford Fitch system's rule of *negation introduction*, and finally *negation elimination*  (which is more commonly known as *double negation elimination*).

*Somehow*… Hmmm …

---

Anyhow, in your other system, what we have so far should translate to something like:

```
 U.         ~(p v ~p), p  |-    p             S1
 Rv+(S1)    ~(p v ~p), p  |-    p v ~p        S2
 U.         ~(p v ~p), p  |-  ~(p v ~p)       S3
 R~+(S2,S3) ~(p v ~p)     |-   ~p             S4
 Rv+(S4)    ~(p v ~p)     |-    p v ~p        S5
```

And you can complete this in three more lines.

Answer (score -1):

I have written a proof of `P or (not P)`

First, a lemma:

```
LEMMA A   P --> (P or (not P))
+---+--------------+----------------------------+
| 1 |      P       |         assumption         |
+---+--------------+----------------------------+
| 2 | P or (not P) | line 1, introduction of or |
+---+--------------+----------------------------+
```

then another lemma:

```
LEMMA B   not P --> (P or (not P))
+---+--------------+----------------------------+
| 1 |      not P   |         assumption         |
+---+--------------+----------------------------+
| 2 | P or (not P) | line 1, introduction of or |
+---+--------------+----------------------------+
```

Finally, the theorem:

```
THEOREM "Bob"  .........  P or (not P)
+---+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
| 1 | P or (not P) | from lemma A, lemma B, and proof by cases |
+---+--------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: No, you cannot use Proof by Cases for this.  Such a proof takes the form of: `A v B`, `A => C`, and `B => C` entails `C`.  Now, you have proven the two conditionals, `P => P v ~P` and `~P => P v ~P`.  However you have *not yet* proven the disjunction `P v ~P` because *that is that you are trying to prove*.